# Display only bicycle mode in MapQuest.js

Tags: javascript, mapquest

I am going through the [MapQuest.js](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/mapquest-js/v1.2/l-mapquest-map/) documentation and essentially i'd like to omit the option for automobiles and replace it with a bicycle.

```
var map = L.mapquest.map('map', {
      center: this.state.center,
      layers: L.mapquest.tileLayer(this.state.baseLayer),
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
      zoomControl: false,
    });
    L.mapquest
      .directionsControl({
        className: 'control-panel',
        routeSummary: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        narrativeControl: {
          enabled: true,
          compactResults: false,
        }
      })
      .addTo(map);
    L.control.zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(map);
  }
```

[image]

I came across this info under **[MapQuest.js > API Reference > mapquest.directions.route](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/directions-api/route/get/)**.

> A class that acts as an interface to the [MapQuest Directions API](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/directions-api/route/get/).
>   Performs either a Route, Optimized Route, or Alternate Route call
>   depending on the routeOptions. If no callback is provided, the route
>   will be automatically rendered on the map. The route markers and
>   ribbons can be styled using the setLayerOptions function. If a
>   callback is provided, the results of the API call will be passed in
>   the error-first callback style.

Can someone show me how I would be able to leverage some of the options in the Directions API?
Am I correct in my thinking this is how you would go about really customizing things?